# How to replace a backslash with two backslashes in C program?

Tags: c

I want to replace every backslash in a string with two backslashes.

I use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int iD, iM, iY = 0;
    char str[255] = "C:\\Users\\Documents";
    printf("%s \n", str);
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0 ; i < (unsigned)strlen( str ) ; i++)
    {
        if ( str[i] == '\\')
        {
            str[i] == "\\\\";
        }
    }

    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :** C:\Users\Documents

**Expected Result :** C:\\Users\\Documents

Comment: first: `if (str[i] == '\\') { /* ... */ }`; second: two characters do not fit into the space of one: you need to make room for the new backslash

Comment: i replace if (str[i] == "\\") by if (str[i] == '\\')  but not solve

Comment: You have to move the part that comes after the backslash to the right by one position and then insert a backslash after the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply replace a single character with two characters! The simplest way to achieve your result is to have a second string, then copy from old to new, one character at a time, adding an extra backslash when that is the character just copied.

Here's a working sample that does this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[255] = "C:\\Users\\Documents";
    char newstr[ 2 * sizeof(str) ]; // As suggested by "chux" - ensure buffer is big enough!
    printf("%s \n", str);
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; i < (int)strlen(str); i++, j++) {
        newstr[j] = str[i];
        if (str[i] == '\\') newstr[++j] = '\\'; // Insert extra backslash
    }
    newstr[j] = '\0'; // We need to add nul-terminator!
    printf("%s", newstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you could always replace the original string with the new one, once you've done the transformation, with a simple `strcpy(str, newstr);` line.